# What is the purpose of @CompatibleWith annotation from Guava?

Tags: java, guava

From the documentation of [com.google.errorprone.annotations.CompatibleWith](http://errorprone.info/api/latest/com/google/errorprone/annotations/CompatibleWith.html?is-external=true):

> Declares that a parameter to a method must be "compatible with" one of the type parameters in the
>   method's enclosing class, or on the method itself. "Compatible with" means that there can exist a
>   "reference casting conversion" from one type to the other (JLS 5.5.1).
>
> For example, Collection.contains(java.lang.Object) would be annotated as follows:
>
> ```
> interface Collection<E> {
>     boolean contains(@CompatibleWith("E") Object o);
> }
> ```
>
> To indicate that invocations of Collection.contains(java.lang.Object) must be passed an argument whose type is compatible with the generic type argument of the Collection instance:

Here is a usage from [com.google.common.cache.Cache](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/24.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html):

```
public interface Cache<K, V> {

    V getIfPresent(@CompatibleWith("K") Object key);

    V get(K key, Callable<? extends V> loader) throws ExecutionException;
...
```

What is the benefit of having `@CompatibleWith("E") Object` instead of `E` as the type of the parameter? And why did they use the `@CompatibleWith` annotation in the `getIfPresent` but not in the `get` method from Cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safe for `getIfPresent` operation to allow objects of "too broad" type (you don't get anything from cache with string keys from `getIfPresent(42)`). On the other hand, for hypothetical `get(Object, Callable)` allowing **inserting** an object of wrong type (eg. `42` instead of a string `"foo"`) would damage the underlying collection, that's why you have compile time checking won't allow it.

Having said that, this code:

```
Cache<String, Foo> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
// and later
Foo value = cache.getIfPresent(42);
```

is most probably wrong, and it makes sense for framework like Error Prone to signal that as a possible bug.

More detailed clarification about "use Object not generic type in safe operations" convention (which isn't used only in Guava, but also in JDK collections framework) is explained in [this old, but still relevant blog post "Why does Set.contains() take an Object, not an E?"](http://smallwig.blogspot.com/2007/12/why-does-setcontains-take-object-not-e.html), where you read:

> Why should code like the following compile?
>
> ```
> Set<Long> set = new HashSet<Long>();
> set.add(10L);
> if (set.contains(10)) {
>   // we won't get here!
> }
> ```
>
> We're asking if the set contains the Integer ten; it's an "obvious"
>   bug, but the compiler won't catch it because `Set.contains()` accepts
>   `Object`. Isn't this stupid and evil?

and later answers the question in title:

> The real difference is that `add()` can cause "damage" to the collection when called with the wrong type, and `contains()` and `remove()` cannot.

The conclusion is also relevant:

> Static analysis plays an extremely important role in the construction of bug-free software.

Which makes sense, because the author, Kevin Bourrillion, is also lead developer of Guava.